# Force SSH connection through a different interface

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing

I want to connect remotely using SSH.

However, I'm not able to while my VPN is active, so I disconnect from the VPN and then connect using the other connection.

How can I force the connection through my other connection when connected to the VPN?

I'm using Windows 7 and PuTTY client.

Comment: Please add more information... Provide a routing table of your current machine, what your client OS is (linux, windows)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 2 options. First, you could modify your routes so that the SSH packets naturally go through the correct interface.

Or you could use the `-b` SSH option (or in a similar way the `-B` one):

```
     -b bind_address
             Use bind_address on the local machine as the source address of
             the connection.  Only useful on systems with more than one
             address.
```

It will bind your SSH client to a chosen local IP address, so that all packets will be emitted through the associated interface.

Comment: what's the second option? i'm curious!

Comment: It would also be helpful to know how to do the equivalent in PuTTY, since the question specified that client.

Comment: It looks like the -b option does not support an IPv6 IP. Am I correct?

Comment: not supported on putty

Answer (score 7):

The issue was with the route taken.

The solution was to update the routing table.
I used the `route` command to add a new route specifying the correct interface and gateway.

The command looks like `route add <destination> mask <netmask> <gateway> <interface>`, for example:

```
route -p add 10.100.10.10 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.0 IF 13
```

`-p` is for persistent so it remains there after reboot. `IF` is for interface and you can get this number from the command `route print`.

Answer (score 4):

You must change the route towards your destination.

A previous answer stated that the `-b` or `-B` options can be used, but normally, if the VPN is activated this does not work because it *reroutes* the traffic towards any destination through the VPN network interface - generally named `tun0`.

Therefore, you must reconfigure the route taken to reach your destination. Let us call it `<destination>`, and `<gate1>` the IP address of the gateway (technically the address of the nexthop router) associated to the different interface that you want to use. With `ip route`, `route` being deprecated, this should be:

`ip route add <destination> via <gate1>`

An alternative is

`ip route add <destination> via <gate1> dev <different interface>`

but given that the address `<gate1>` is already associated with your different interface, here `<different interface>`, that changes nothing.

What matters here, is to specify it is `<gate1>`, the gateway of your different interface, which has to be traversed, instead of that of the VPN.

Comment: This worked for me with `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.241 dev eth0` to access the 192.168.1.xxx subnet via eth0 (metric 300, IP address 192.168.1.241) instead of wlan0 (metric 200 = higher preference)